# How to promote a question on another Stack?

Tags: discussion

I often see questions that are on-topic here, but which may be of interest to stackizens on other sites.  What is the correct way to cross-promote a question like this?

For example, [this question about political islam](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37629/difference-between-islamism-and-political-islam) is an excellent fit for our site. Since it's on topic here we can't migrate it anywhere else (nor do we want to!). However, the querant may get good quality answers from the fine people at Islam.SE.

Since the question shouldn't be migrated, how can I make users on Islam.SE aware of this question? Should I simply post something in their meta about it? Or is there some other tool?

The Islam question is only an example. There are other examples I've seen in political philosophy, economic policy or political economy, law, and other fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, chat is a good option for this.

Unfortunately, [Jaami'at StackExchange al-Islamyya](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3819/jaamiat-stackexchange-al-islamyya), the main chat room for Islam Stack Exchange, does not seem to be particularly active.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I've posted something in there. We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score -4):

## Suggest in a comment that the OP ask there as well

If something's on-topic in the current stack, but would also potentially be on-topic in another stack, you can always suggest to OP that they post some (stack-appropriate) version of the question in the other stack as well. Nothing is forcing a user to only ask a question in one place where it's relevant; if it's on-topic in both places, it can certainly be asked in both places.

I'm not saying the question should be worded identically in both places, of course. If the question needs editing to be appropriate and on-topic in the other stack, the OP should make sure to do that before asking in the other stack. (And, of course, not every question that might relate to another stack will be allowed there.) The OP should make sure the question is tailored to the community it's being posted to.

Comment: Cross-posting questions to multiple stacks is frowned upon. Sometimes, however, it is possible to ask similar questions on different stacks with a different emphasis, but they should never be the same or even substantially similar. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu